# Java Threading Basics

Tags: java, multithreading

What is the difference between the two thread calls below?
Will the two calls act similarly?

NOTE: I am not using #1 & #2 at the same time, which is the best option.

```
private void startConnections(){
    ServerThread server = new ServerThread();
    server.start(); // #1
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(server);
    serverThread.start(); //#2
}

class ServerThread extends Thread{
    public void run(){}
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first approach is acceptable, but discouraged. The second one works, but is broken/hard to understand. Consider the third one:

```
class ServerRunnable implements Runnable {
  public void run(){}
}

Runnable run = new ServerRunnable();
Thread serverThread = new Thread(run);
serverThread.start();  //#3
```

## #1

This is pretty common approach - in order to create a new thread you are simply subclassing it and calling `start()` method. Many people, including myself, find this idiom being a poor practice - it unnecessarily couples task (contents of `run()` method) with threading (`Thread` class).

## #2

I have never seen code like this and although technically working, I would correct it immediately. Even though you are creating a *thread* instance, you are passing it to another thread and starting the latter. So why creating the first thread on the first place? Note that `Thread` also implements `Runnable`, so it technically works, but is really awkward.

## #3

So what do I recommend? Implement `Runnable` interface that is not coupled to threading. You cannot *run* `Runnable` in a separate thread alone, you have to explicitly create that thread. But having raw `Runnable` also allows you to easily switch from native thread to for instance thread-pool.

Technically you can extend `Thread` and put such a "runnable" in a thread pool, but this is really hard to understand and you are also unnecessarily carrying `Thread` baggage (it is quite a big class).

Comment: As recommended in the official sources: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: The explanation is perfect and even the link too. SO, whenever I want to create a thread for class, Runnable is the best option right? <br>
And Thread must be used to run the Runnable Object. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @mrb: yes, you are correct. The link provided by *madth3* explains it pretty well.