# Java join() method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an example that seems strange to me.

```
public class Join {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                    }
                }
        );
        Thread t2 = new Thread(t1);
        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");
        t1.start();
        try {t1.join();} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

We'll see printed only t1.
If we'll comment "t1.join", we'll se the expected output (t1 t2).
Why ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second thread is created incorrectly:

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(t1);
```

I can't support it by documentation, but in the source code of `Thread.run()` I see:

```
if (target != null) {
    target.run();
}
```

Where `target` is `Runnable` instance. When the `Thread` is done, it clears the `target` variable:

```
private void exit() {
  //...
  target = null;
```

This means that when the first thread is done (`join()` method) it clears the `target` and the second thread does nothing. When `join()` is removed, both access the same `target` of `t1` (race condition).

## TL;DR

Never create a thread using another thread instance (even though it implements `Runnable`). Instead create a separate `Runnable` and pass it:

```
final Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
};
Thread t1 = new Thread(run, "t1");
Thread t2 = new Thread(run, "t2");  //new Thread(t1, "t2"); is incorrect!
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

You don't need any `join()`s here, by default these are non-daemon threads.

## See also

- [Java Threading Basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649357) (discussion on #2)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand this is a very bad practice and of course join() here is for no reason, it was just from curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

This is because main thread waits for `t1` to die when you call `t1.join()`.
And when you do this

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(t1);
```

you are passing `t1` as target object whose `run` method is called.

Comment: when I call t1.join(), main thread is waiting for t1 to die and not t1 is waiting

Comment: When `main` thread calls `t1.join()`, the one who's waiting is `main`. If you run it in a debugger you'll see that `t2.start()` is executed also.

Comment: Sorry, My fault. I mistakenly wrote it vice versa. Corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Add before `t2.start();`:

```
System.out.println("t1 is alive: " + t1.isAlive());
```

If `main` thread is waiting for `t1` to die then `t2.start()` can not run `t1`'s `run` method. Otherwise, without waiting for `t1` to die, `t2` can run `t1`'s `run` method.